# Socket Direct Protocol error: "Address family not supported by protocol"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, infiniband

I thought I would try out SDP on our infiniband hardware.

However, when I try to add AF_INET_SDP as the first argument to `socket()` I get the following error:

```
"Address family not supported by protocol".
```

Originally I had:

```
#define AF_INET_SDP 26
```

But after doing some reading, noticed a patch applied some time back to change this value to 27.

When set to 26 I get the error:

```
"Error binding socket: No such device"
```

Has anyone managed to get SDP working on Ubuntu 12.04? what did you do to get it up and running?

I have installed libsdp1 and libsdpa-dev

Using the LD_PRELOAD method on iperf I also get the first error:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libsdp.so iperf -s
dir: /tmp/libsdp.log.1000 file: /tmp/libsdp.log.1000/log
socket failed: Address family not supported by protocol
bind failed: Bad file descriptor
```

Therefore I assume 27 is the correct domain number.

Comment: It seems that SDP support has been removed from the latest OFED stack (on windows at least).  It looks like there is meant to be a kernel module to go with the userland.  I think maybe this is why the kernel module isn't in the mainline. SDP appears to have been dropped for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

SDP hasn't been accepted on the mainline linux kernel. On recent fedora, they don't ship it, neither the user space libsdp.
If you still want to experiment, Matt is right, the module in question is 'ib_sdp'.
try modprobe ib_sdp and run your example again.

Comment: In fact I read a comment that there may be a licensing issue with SDP.  Another way forward may be RSockets which talks about being SDP license free?